# Change Google Maps review sort with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, xpath, webdriverwait

I am facing interesting issue with my **Web Scraping** use case. I need to get newest **Google Maps reviews**. 
 I want to sort reviews by latest date. And all tutorials I am watching is in English, but in my native language the UI is different than in those tutorials. 
I am able to click on the button using **Selenium** and button's **XPATH**, but I don't know how to change the sorting options from the visible drop menu.

```
# Click the sort button
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="pane"]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div[8]/button').click()
```

[image: Chrome inspection]

**select_by_visible_text()** and **select_by_value()** doesn't work for me as I cannot select the button and doesn't work on div.

URL I am using : [Link](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Senukai/@54.6832836,25.183965,12z/data=!4m11!1m2!2m1!1svilnius+senukai!3m7!1s0x46dd94055529fabf:0xb1132b0ad981d43b!8m2!3d54.7098368!4d25.2999662!9m1!1b1!15sCg92aWxuaXVzIHNlbnVrYWkiA4gBAVoRIg92aWxuaXVzIHNlbnVrYWmSARhidWlsZGluZ19tYXRlcmlhbHNfc3RvcmU)
To see my UI change to LITHUANIAN language.

Comment: please share the exact link to the page you are working on. It's public page, there is no problem with that.

Comment: Prophet, updated my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you have to learn how to create correct XPath locators.
Long XPath expressions are too fragile.
The "Sort Reviews" button locator instead of
`//*[@id="pane"]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div[8]/button` can be
`//button[@aria-label='Sort reviews']` or
`//button[@data-value='Sort']`
After clicking this button, to sort reviews by latest date you can click this element: `//li[@data-index='1']`
So basically this will work:

```py
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//li[@data-index='1']").click()
```

But since you need to wait for dialog to open after clicking the Sort button you need to utilize Expected Condition wait, as following:

```py
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//li[@data-index='1']"))).click()
```

You will need the following imports for this:

```py
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me, try in my native LITHUANIAN language. ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted.

Comment: Did you use a `wait` or just a direct `driver.find_element_by_xpath("//li[@data-index='1']").click()`? The exception you getting is not caused by the language differences.

Comment: You are right, your code works as well after some tweaking. Thank you

Comment: Great, I'm happy I could help :)

Answer (score 1):

This code should work.

I added a webdriverwait after clicking on the 'Sort' button to wait until the all the options in the dropdown are visible, then clicked on 'Highest rating'.
`//li[@role='menuitemradio'])[3]` refers to the 3rd element in the dropdown which is the 'Higest rating'. I tried using the text to be specific and not count on element index, but somehow it is not working. But the below code does sort the reviews.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://www.google.com/maps/place/Senukai/@54.6832836,25.183965,12z/data=!4m11!1m2!2m1!1svilnius+senukai!3m7!1s0x46dd94055529fabf:0xb1132b0ad981d43b!8m2!3d54.7098368!4d25.2999662!9m1!1b1!15sCg92aWxuaXVzIHNlbnVrYWkiA4gBAVoRIg92aWxuaXVzIHNlbnVrYWmSARhidWlsZGluZ19tYXRlcmlhbHNfc3RvcmU")
print(driver.title)
time.sleep(5)
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[@data-value='Sort']").click()
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//li[@role='menuitemradio']")))
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "(//li[@role='menuitemradio'])[3]").click()
time.sleep(2)
driver.quit()
```

P.S I used `time.sleep` occasionally to make a quick code, but it would be a good practice to use `WebdriverWait` in lieu of `time.sleep`

Comment: Doesn't work for me, try in my native LITHUANIAN language. ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted.

Comment: ok, can you point to the element DOM in a snapshot? For when I hit the url you gave, it opens in English for that is my native in my OS.
Basically, what I think is you just need to change the English text to Lithuanian. What I mean is, instead of using //button[@aria-label='Sort reviews'] you may use //button[@aria-label='Labiausiai atitinkantys']

Comment: Damn, I just figured it out. Thank you. Your code worked after some tweaking. Thank you

Comment: Glad to know! Throw some light on what tweaks you did, so it would be useful for others in future. Thanks!